# How to use two map function with two fetching URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I have two API that I should turn them array like that

```json
[
            {
                key: "0",
                label: 'Installation',
                children: [
                    { key: "0-0", label: 'Getting Started', url: 'https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html' },
                    { key: "0-1", label: 'Add React', url: 'https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html' },
                    { key: "0-2", label: 'Create an App', url: 'https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html' },
                    { key: "0-3", label: 'CDN Links', url: 'https://reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html' }
                ]
            },
            {
                key: "1",
                label: 'Main Concepts',
                children: [
                    { key: "1-0", label: 'Hello World', url: 'https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html' },
                    { key: "1-1", label: 'Introducing JSX', url: 'https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html' },
                    { key: "1-2", label: 'Rendering Elements', url: 'https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html' },
                    { key: "1-3", label: 'Components and Props', url: 'https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html' },
                    { key: "1-4", label: 'State and LifeCycle', url: 'https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html' },
                    { key: "1-5", label: 'Handling Events', url: 'https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html' }
                ]
            }
        ];
```

By the way, I have two API, one of them get all categories, the second API is to take the names of the children. So I created chained fetch, but I can not take the children object correctly. children array turns that `'children: Promise {<fulfilled>: Array(11)}'`
What does fulfilled mean here, because my code not working due to that reason?
I want to share my code also:

```js
 getCategories() {
    return fetch('https://challenge.fnaghshin.com/api/cat')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((d) => {
        return Promise.all(
          d.map((e) => {
            return {
              key: e.id,
              label: e.name,
              date: e.created_at,
              children: fetch(
                `https://challenge.fnaghshin.com/api/catpro/${e.id}`
              )
                .then((res) => res.json())
                .then((d) =>
                  d.map((e) => {
                    return {
                      key: e.id,
                      label: e.name,
                    };
                  })
                ),
            };
          })
        );
      });
  }
```

I also used `Promise.all()` to wait all promises fulfilled than turn me right array, but I failed.

Comment: Are you returning a promise in Promise.all() ?

Comment: @Invizi no how can I do that?

Comment: `fetch()` is an asynchronous function. `async` functions return promises. `Promise.all()` is not recursive so doesn't resolve those deeply nested promises.

Comment: @Ouroborus so can you help me to solve this deeply nested promise.

Comment: @sayinmehmet47 You can run my answer and see if it does what you wanted.

Comment: I tried to give you some more background on why your code didn't work and make it more readable and concise, please check it and don't forget to accept the answer thatt solves your question / problem best: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69412270/8412038

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Promise.all()` expects an array of promises, but you were returning an array of objects. The promise was nested in the `children` prop of the objects. So what we need to do, is map over these objects and return the nested prop `children` and feed that to `Promise.all()`

I added an async funtion to the second `then` block, so I can use `await` with `Promise.all()`. That causes the execution of the code to wait until all promises, that is all `children` have resolved. After that I can simply return the result.

```
function getCategories() {
  return fetch('https://challenge.fnaghshin.com/api/cat')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then(async (d) => {
      const withChildren = d.map((e) => {
        return {
          key: e.id,
          label: e.name,
          date: e.created_at,
          children: fetch(`https://challenge.fnaghshin.com/api/catpro/${e.id}`).then(res => res.json())
        }
      })
      await Promise.all(withChildren.map(item => item.children))
      return withChildren
    })
}
```

The `429 (Too Many Requests)` seems to be a rate limit, when you fire the requests too often within a certain time. I had it, too. Now it is gone again.

PS: Don't use await in `map()` in this case, as this makes the execution last longer. Because in each iteration of the map, it will `await` the response of the `fetch()`, before going to the next iteration and firing the next `fetch()`. So instead of firing them all at once (basically), you fire them one after another has resolved. It's faster to fire them all at once, and then await `Promise.all()`.

Answer (score 4):

The cleanest solution IMO is to use async/await, with nested Promises it quickly gets fairly unreadable.

```
async function getCategories() {
  const response = await fetch("https://challenge.fnaghshin.com/api/cat");
  const categories = await response.json();

  const childrenResponses = await Promise.all(
    categories.map((cat) =>
      fetch(`https://challenge.fnaghshin.com/api/catpro/${cat.id}`)
    )
  );

  const childrenData = await Promise.all(
    childrenResponses.map((response) => response.json())
  );

  return categories.map((cat, index) => ({
    key: cat.id,
    label: cat.name,
    date: cat.created_at,
    children: childrenData[index].map((child) => ({
      key: child.id,
      label: child.title
    }))
  }));
}
```

So first you get your categories, that's pretty simple. Then what you want to do is to use `Promise.all()` on list of fetch calls with IDs you have from categories (`childrenResponses`). Then you have to do the same because of `.json()` in fetch (it would be even cleaner with e.g. `axios` or similar higher level library instead of `fetch`), and once you have categories and childrenData you just have to map it the way you want. You can make it a bit more concise by doing e.g. this instead:

```
const categories = await fetch(
  "https://challenge.fnaghshin.com/api/cat"
).then((res) => res.json());
```

although in my opinion it's less readable. You should probably also do some error handling, e.g. with try/catch.

Comment: this kind of usage also give 429 error. look     ProductService.js:30 GET https://challenge.fnaghshin.com/api/catpro/8 429 (Too Many Requests)

Comment: It's 99% related to how you're calling this function. It works perfectly fine in isolation (you can even run it in DevTools console or something). Also you might be just blocked by the API temporarily if you've been spamming it with calls until now. Wait a couple minutes/hours and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a promise based version. I split up the main function into parts, so it's easier to read.

Do note that because you are makeing many requests to the API, you are likely to get a `429: too many requests` warning.

To solve that you can either use proxies for each request, or you can check the status code and wait for the time the response tells you to wait.

```js
const URL = 'https://challenge.fnaghshin.com/api/cat';
const CHILDREN_URL = `https://challenge.fnaghshin.com/api/catpro/`;

function getCategories() {
  return fetch(URL)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => Promise.all(data.map(getSubCategories)));
}

function getSubCategories(data) {
  return fetch(CHILDREN_URL + data.id)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(info => ({
      key: data.id,
      label: data.name,
      date: data.created_at,
      children: info.map(e => ({
        key: e.id,
        label: e.title,
      })),
    }));
}

getCategories()
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.log)
```